# Using Message Pack + LZ4 Compression with .NET Signalr

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, msgpack

[The documentation](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) of **MessagePack for C#** states that using LZ4 compression you can achieve compact binary sizes of your payload. in docs you can use:

```cs
var lz4Options = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithCompression(MessagePackCompression.Lz4BlockArray);
MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(obj, lz4Options);
```

So it basically says that upon calling every **Serialize()** and **Deserialize()** methods, you should specify compression options exclusively.

But when working with [.NET Signalr](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr), you don't directly call these methods. Nuget Package  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack/) does that for you. you only have to tell the applications serviceCollection to do so in **ConfigureServices()** method:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSignalR().AddMessagePackProtocol();
}
```

So I'm curious how to specify **MessagePackSerializationOptions** for signalr to use LZ4 compression.
I already tried changing default option configuration in applications main method:

```cs
MessagePackSerializer.DefaultOptions = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithCompression(MessagePackCompression.Lz4BlockArray);
```

But firstly it isn't recommended and secondly It doesn't seem to work :D

Comment: MessagePackCompression has 2 mode, Have you tried MessagePackCompression. Lz4Block? Lz4BlockArray is introduced in MesagePack v2, you need to find a computability SignalR version for Lz4 compression

Comment: I'm also curious. I know you can do this, but then I think we need something for decompression on the JavaScript side? At least my app broke: `services.AddSignalR().AddMessagePackProtocol(options => options.SerializerOptions = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithCompression(MessagePackCompression.Lz4BlockArray).WithSecurity(MessagePackSecurity.UntrustedData));`

Answer (score 0):

In the main method, using the builder pattern, you need to specify the options in a lambda expression.

I don't know what you mean by "not recommended" but this is a Microsoft implementation. If you think they haven't follow best practices for the implementation details you can take it up with them in their GitHub pages these days. Your syntax wouldn't change. You're just turning the feature on.

Here is my starting config for reference.

**HUB SIDE:**

```cs
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
})
.AddMessagePackProtocol(messagePackOptions =>
{
    messagePackOptions.SerializerOptions = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard
        .WithCompression(MessagePackCompression.Lz4Block)
        .WithSecurity(MessagePackSecurity.UntrustedData);
});
```

**CLIENT SIDE:**

```cs
_connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(HubUrl, options =>
    {
        // Configure authentication here:
        options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    })
    .AddMessagePackProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerOptions = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard
            .WithCompression(MessagePackCompression.Lz4Block)
            .WithSecurity(MessagePackSecurity.UntrustedData);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders()
            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
            .AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug)
            .AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", LogLevel.Debug)
            ;
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
```